# Connect Java remotely to MYSQL DB on another network

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to write a java application that uses a mysql database to store and retrieve information. I am still just a beginner and I do not have a lot of knowledge on web hosting providers and server architecture. In this application, several clients will have to access this remote database located on a server machine maybe.

Currently, I can connect to the database from the same computer that runs the mysql server (I am using workbench by the way). Any suggestions on what should I do?

```
public static Connection openDatabase()
{ 
    Connection myConn;
    try {

      myConn = 
            DriverManager.getConnection(Configs.getProperty("DatabaseURL"));

     return myConn;
   } catch (SQLException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;
}
```

The url is:

```
jdbc:mysql://Atomic-PC:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useSSL=false&user=root&password=password
```

Comment: Add your db connecting code, so we can provide you in depth answer

Comment: @ChathuraBuddhika, I had added my code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to connect to remote database then yo need to change the database url from `localhost` to remote server ip address.

```
jdbc:mysql://Atomic-PC:3306/test
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://<db-server-ip-address>:<db-server-port>/<db-name>
```

Assuming, remote server ip address is `10.234.05.123` and database port number is `3300` and database name is `remoteDB`. Then,

```
jdbc:mysql://10.234.05.123:3300/remoteDB
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I am using mysql as my rdbms. I manage my database manually through mysql workbench on my local machine. How can I get the ip address of my db? Would I be able to access the db from another network?

Comment: @MariaGonzalez You need ip-address of server where you have installed mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to find connection URL, port and credential from MySql workbench you are using. If hosting provider provides a public IP for DB server you should be able to access it from anywhere by using following code in Java.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourDBName";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, password);
    if (!con.isClosed()) {
      con.close();
    }
  }
}
```

For this reason you have to import mysql connection driver to your application first.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you know how can I get a hostname that is visible to clients in other networks?

Comment: You can use Query SELECT USER(); to get username and hostname. It will return like username@hostname

Answer (score 0):

your web hosting company should be able to provide you with the url:port which you can use in your connection string to connect to MySQL(or any other remote db for that matter)

Comment: What web hosting companies would you recommend? Which plan should I get?

Comment: There are sooo many of them..just do a google search for best web hosting companies..All you need to make sure they provide you with MySQL server to connect to.